# Sending a message to a view from a different method in controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm making a project where my login form goes to another function in the controller with a different name. I want to send error message in the current view from that function. How can I do it? Thank you

Comment: you can call controller function using AJAX and then show on the client-side response, another way is to return the same view with some data in Model and update your Razor code to show this error but first approach is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TempData["Keyword"] for this. If the controller follows another httpRequest then also it holds the data until it is read.

**Controller**

```
TempData["Error"]="This is error";
```

**View from Other Controller**

```
<lable>@TempData["Error"]</lable>
```

Fro better understanding

### [Click HERE](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-tempdata-in-asp-net/)

Comment: Happy to help danyal and please vote up when u can.